# Entering and leaving Europe (i.e., the Schengen Zone) several times in a month

Tags: schengen, europe, borders, repeat-visits

I will be giving several talks across Europe, US and Asia in a space of 70 days (2 months more or less). My itinerary starts in the Schengen area, then leads me to Asia and back to the Schengen area and then to the US and back to the Schengen Area and so on.

My question is whether I am going to have issues crossing the Schengen borders with all the entries, which is not supposed to happen since I will be exiting the Schengen area for the last time before the maximum permitted stay for my passport (Argentina).

Comment: Are you getting paid for these talks? If so you may need a special visa.

Comment: Pretty good question. It's a part of my job and I'm getting payed but not by the organizers and not in the countries where the talks are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A non-visa national, such as Argentine nationals, can pass in and out of the zone as long as the 90/180 rule is observed **AND** the person satisfies the landing interview with a valid premise. As a general rule, all interaction with border officials is governed by personal impact and articulation skills (along with demonstrating an understanding of the rules), so be prepared for it.

In your case, you can present an itinerary of the talks you are giving along with any personal tourist side-trips you have planned.

Comment: Nice, I have passed several borders several times so the interaction with the border officials does not scare me. I even have accommodation, a medical insurance and valid means to show I'm financially stable for the entire trip.